# Android + SSL: Error Not Trusted Server Certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have visited many places in order to solve this problem but not to do.

Android returns error when attempting an SSL connection "Not Trusted Server Certificate".
https://google.cl/ work, but https://autoservicio.movistar.cl/ dont work :-/
My project:

```
package com.drawcoders.saldomovistarchile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SaldoMovistarChileActivity extends Activity {
    TextView statusText;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        statusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        login();
    }

    void login(){       
        try {
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
            socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier)hostnameVerifier);
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
            SingleClientConnManager mngr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mngr, client.getParams());

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://autoservicio.movistar.cl/login/loginTop");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rut", "1000000"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dv", "0"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idRut", "10000000-0"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clave", "00000000"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

            // HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            statusText.setText("Finalizado!");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            statusText.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            statusText.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            statusText.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears (judging off my Android device: Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.1.1) that the CA root certificate(s) used for the domain *autoservicio.movistar.cl* are not provided on this version of Android and probably versions prior to 4.1.1.

For sites you trust try the solutions provided here: [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)

Comment: The real fix is to install the intermediate certificate to the web server.

Answer (score 1):

The website, https://autoservicio.movistar.cl does not return an intermediate certificate so the client can not build a chain to a trusted root. Firefox gives an error also.

This SSL checker shows that only the server certificate is returned:

http://certlogik.com/ssl-checker/autoservicio.movistar.cl

The missing intermediate certificate is this one:

CN = VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3,OU = Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10,OU = VeriSign Trust Network,O = "VeriSign, Inc.",C = US

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIGKTCCBRGgAwIBAgIQZBvoIM4CCBPzLU0tldZ+ZzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
>   yjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQL
>   ExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTowOAYDVQQLEzEoYykgMjAwNiBWZXJp
>   U2lnbiwgSW5jLiAtIEZvciBhdXRob3JpemVkIHVzZSBvbmx5MUUwQwYDVQQDEzxW
>   ZXJpU2lnbiBDbGFzcyAzIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0
>   aG9yaXR5IC0gRzUwHhcNMTAwMjA4MDAwMDAwWhcNMjAwMjA3MjM1OTU5WjCBvDEL
>   MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQLExZW
>   ZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTswOQYDVQQLEzJUZXJtcyBvZiB1c2UgYXQg
>   aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3JwYSAoYykxMDE2MDQGA1UEAxMtVmVy
>   aVNpZ24gQ2xhc3MgMyBJbnRlcm5hdGlvbmFsIFNlcnZlciBDQSAtIEczMIIBIjAN
>   BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmdacYvAV9IGaQQhZjxOdF8mfUdza
>   sVLv/+NB3eDfxCjG4615HycQmLi7IJfBKERBD+qpqFLPTU4bi7u1xHbZzFYG7rNV
>   ICreFY1xy1TIbxfNiQDk3P/hwB9ocenHKS5+vDv85burJlSLZpDN9pK5MSSAvJ5s
>   1fx+0uFLjNxC+kRLX/gYtS4w9D0SmNNiBXNUppyiHb5SgzoHRsQ7AlYhv/JRT9Cm
>   mTnprqU/iZucff5NYAclIPe712mDK4KTQzfZg0EbawurSmaET0qO3n40mY5o1so5
>   BptMs5pITRNGtFghBMT7oE2sLktiEuP7TfbJUQABH/weaoEqOOC5T9YtRQIDAQAB
>   o4ICFTCCAhEwEgYDVR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADBwBgNVHSAEaTBnMGUGC2CGSAGG
>   +EUBBxcDMFYwKAYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbS9j cHMwKgYIKwYBBQUHAgIwHhocaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3JwYTAO
>   BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwbQYIKwYBBQUHAQwEYTBfoV2gWzBZMFcwVRYJaW1hZ2Uv
>   Z2lmMCEwHzAHBgUrDgMCGgQUj+XTGoasjY5rw8+AatRIGCx7GS4wJRYjaHR0cDov
>   L2xvZ28udmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3ZzbG9nby5naWYwNAYDVR0lBC0wKwYIKwYBBQUH
>   AwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCBglghkgBhvhCBAEGCmCGSAGG+EUBCAEwNAYIKwYBBQUHAQEE
>   KDAmMCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8vb2NzcC52ZXJpc2lnbi5jb20wNAYDVR0f
>   BC0wKzApoCegJYYjaHR0cDovL2NybC52ZXJpc2lnbi5jb20vcGNhMy1nNS5jcmww
>   KAYDVR0RBCEwH6QdMBsxGTAXBgNVBAMTEFZlcmlTaWduTVBLSS0yLTcwHQYDVR0O
>   BBYEFNebfNgioBX33a1fzimbWMO8RgC1MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFH/TZafC3ey78DAJ
>   80M5+gKvMzEzMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQBxtX1zUkrd1000Ky6vlEalSVAC
>   T/gvF3DyE9wfIYaqwk98NzzURniuXXhv0bpavBCrWDbFjGIVRWAXIeLVQqh3oVXY
>   QwRR9m66SOZdTLdE0z6k1dYzmp8N5tdOlkSVWmzWoxZTDphDzqS4w2Z6BVxiEOgb
>   Ett9LnZQ/9/XaxvMisxx+rNAVnwzeneUW/ULU/sOX7xo+68q7jA3eRaTJX9NEP9X
>   +79uOzMh3nnchhdZLUNkt6Zmh+q8lkYZGoaLb9e3SQBb26O/KZru99MzrqP0nkzK XmnUG623kHdq2FlveasB+lXwiiFm5WVu/XzT3x7rfj8GkPsZC9MGAht4Q5mo
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----